# how can open a photoshop PSD file in xcode iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4

I am trying to develop an ios application.The application needs to open a photoshope psd file  . Is any method for this.
if anybody know please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit: do you want get at the graphics inside the .psd file to display them as elements (buttons, images, etc.) in your user interface, or do you actually want to be able to directly edit the .psd file?

Comment: yes, i want to be able to directly edit the  .psd file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php?ImageMagick=mha8gckk77j8h84nsuf0ld25b5#iOS). They have an iOS compiled binary that you can link to in your application.

**Edit :** I would advise against writing a parser yourself considering [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xee/source#108) :

```
    // At this point, I'd like to take a moment to speak to you about the Adobe PSD format.
    // PSD is not a good format. PSD is not even a bad format. Calling it such would be an
    // insult to other bad formats, such as PCX or JPEG. No, PSD is an abysmal format. Having
    // worked on this code for several weeks now, my hate for PSD has grown to a raging fire
    // that burns with the fierce passion of a million suns.
```

Comment: That's one of the best in-line code comments I've ever seen (well, at least so far this year).